# Editing text size of a sub item in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to edit the textSize, textColor and textStyle of the subitem in a listView.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/order_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/network_progress_bar"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="normal"
    android:textSize="@dimen/subhead"
    android:textColor="@color/black_percent_87"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    >
```

What attributes of a listView can i use to change the color, style and size of the subitems?

Comment: are you using Custom Listview

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a custom layout for list row
like this...

http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html